# Get groups of 4 elements from name value list using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I am wanting to loop through this list of name value pairs and grab them in groups of 4.

The data would be like:

```
value1 1
value2 1
value3 1
value4 1
value1 2
value2 2
value3 2
value4 2
```

and it would group it as 1 list that contains

```
value1 1
value2 1
value3 1
value4 1
```

and another list that contains

```
value1 2
value2 2
value3 2
value4 2
```

I know this can be done easily with a for loop, but I am wondering if there is a good way to do it with LINQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split List into Sublists with LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will group by every 4 items (a, b, c, d), (e, f, g, h), (i, j)

```
var abc = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j" };

var xyz = abc.Select((e, i) => new { Item = e, Grouping = (i / 4) }).GroupBy(e => e.Grouping);
```

Answer (score 5):

There's nothing built into the framework to do this easily, but [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) has the [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) method:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<DataItem>> groups = source.Batch(4);

foreach (IEnumerable<DataItem> group in groups)
{
    foreach (DataItem item in group)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, just by coincidence I wanted to recommend the same ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am going to look into this, but i want to try and stay inside the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx).

Comment: Are you grouping by 4 elements at a time, or grouping on the second value in your example?

Comment: I am grabbing 4 elements at a time.