# LINQ Numerical Grouping

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Looking for a way to group in sets of `n` elements with LINQ.

I.e:

`{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}`:

- Grouped By 2: `{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},{7,8},{9}}`
- Grouped By 3: `{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}`
- Grouped By 4: `{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9}}`
- Etc...

Only way I can think of doing something like this at the moment is by using an anonymous type to generate a group index, then grouping by that index. I'm looking for a cleaner solution if possible.

**Example:**

```
int groupSize = n;
int groupCount = 0;
int groupNum = 0;

IEnumerable<T> items;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,T>> groups = items
    .Select(i => new 
    {
      Index = ((groupCount++) % groupSize == 0) ? groupNum++ : groupNum,
      Item = i
    })
    .GroupBy(c => c.Index, d => d.Item);
```

I'd like to avoid something this nasty if possible.

Comment: It would be awesome if there's a better way, but I don't think there is.

Comment: I mean, I could always write the above as an extension function, I just don't know how the delayed execution would work with something like that. I'd prefer things to be as LINQ'y as possible :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var values = new []{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

groups = values.Select((v, i) => new { index = i, value = v })
    .GroupBy(k => k.index / n, e => e.value);
```

Comment: !!! The Index, I forgot `.Select` could return it! Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686497/get-groups-of-4-elements-from-name-value-list-using-linq-in-c/2686582#2686582). It still uses an anonymous type, but I don't think it's as "nasty" as your example.